# Bootstrap selectpicker class is not working with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my application I need to use a drop down list with a tick mark in each option item in drop down list. I used the following code.

```
<select id="cbo-db-selection" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control bs-select-hidden" ng-model="selectedLibrary" ng-options="opt.DatabaseName as opt.DatabaseName or opt in DBLibraries"></select>
```

I'm using angular js to bind the drop down list. But it is not binding the list items if I use the selectpicker class. But the drop down list is binding from angular js if I remove the selectpicker class and bs-select-hidden class. The code is as given below.

```
<select id="cbo-db-selection" class="show-tick form-control" ng-model="selectedLibrary" ng-options="opt as opt.DatabaseName for opt in DBLibraries"></select>
```

But now there is no tick mark in the selected item. How to fix this issue. Please help me.

Comment: which selectpicker are you actually using? please link ur library

Comment: @SimoneZandara, I'm using select picker in bootstrap-select.js